# How is synchronizing is a problem for multiple mutable references in Rust?

Tags: memory, rust, heap-memory

I was reading Rust documentation section 4 and saw a code like this:

```rust
let mut s = String::from("hello");

let r1 = &mut s;
let r2 = &mut s;

println!("{}, {}", r1, r2);
```

So the documentation says that you cannot have multiple mutable references in Rust. Okay, makes sense but doc says three behaviors occurs if you could use, one of them is:

**There’s no mechanism being used to synchronize access to the data.**

Is there a need of mechanism to synchronize it? I mean we already use pointers to the heap or to another pointer that points to the heap.

[image: rust-diagram]

I mean in this diagram, let's say that we have `s2` and `s3` as mutable references to `s1`.
`s1` already has a pointer to the heap so `s2` and `s3` has pointers to s1. When we change `s2` or `s3` doesn't the memory change in the heap?

```rust
let mut s1 = String::from("Hello");
let s2 = &mut s1;
s2.push_str(", world");
```

In here the memory in the heap that `s1` points to is changed so the `s3` already points to that memory so doesn't it already synchronized?

**I got the problem that why we should not use multiple mutable references. I just assume that we could. Rust says there is no mechanism to sync access to the data. My question is, we already have pointers to the heap from each reference so when we change the value in the heap it will all be synced because they are not values, they're just pointers to the heap and the value in the heap is changed?**

Comment: Pointers do not provide synchronization.

Comment: it's a rule, there is nothing to more.

Comment: Some good reasons on why: https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/05/17/the-problem-with-shared-mutability/

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if the following was allowed:

```rust
let mut maybe_five = Some(5);
let mut zero = 0;

// first mutable borrow
let ref_five = &mut maybe_five;

// second mutable borrow
// number_ref is a reference inside maybe_five's Some
let number_ref = match &mut maybe_five {
    Some(ref mut five) => five,
    _ => &mut zero,
};

// invalidate number_ref by making the value it points to invalid
*ref_five = None;

// now we write into a None???
*number_ref = 10;
```

We would be able to do all kinds of undefined behavior in safe rust.

Comment: Not gonna say anything about some other languages allowing this 

Comment: No, i got the understanding of why we should not have multiple mutable references. But i just wonder that behavior i mentioned about: synchronization. My question is that why we need a mechanism to sync mutable references **if we could have that functionality** in Rust.

Comment: @DoğukanAkkaya That functionality does exist in rust: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html

Comment: The reason why syncing isn't the default is that it is not computationally cheap to do. Mutex for example does locking. And also because it isn't necessary if we don't have multiple mutable references.

Comment: This is what i'm asking actually. Isn't syncing is already the default behavior of references? When the value in the heap changes, all of the references will be sync because they are just pointers, not values. I mean `x` points to 0x00 address, `y` points to 0x00 address and `z` owns that value. When `z` changes `x` and `y` will already be synced right? I just don't understand why syncing is one of the problems about using multiple mutable references. I understand other problems with that approach, just not that.